# Referencing a cell in Sheet 2 from Sheet 1 makes Out of range error

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, birt

I am developing a BIRT report which uses Apache POI when export the report to excel by the excel emitter uk.co.spudsoft.

I can reference a sheet which is already created from another sheet. But referencing a cell from a sheet which is not generated, makes out of range error by Apache POI. But in Excel we have this options.

How can I solve without arranging the Excel sheet order?

Comment: Do you mean that you are trying to create a reference to a cell, but that cell is in a sheet that hasn't been added to the workbook yet?

Comment: I am still not sure of how that execution goes..